# Class not using overridden equals

Tags: java, overriding, equals

Why does it not reach the print line "here"? In other words, why is it not using my overridden equals?
Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.*;
class NumberClass extends Object{
    private int number;

    public NumberClass(int n){
        number=n;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        System.out.println("here");
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return number+"";
    }   
}
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set <NumberClass> set= new HashSet<NumberClass>();
        set.add(new NumberClass(0));
        set.add(new NumberClass(0));
        System.out.println(set);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `HashSet` uses the hash code to test whether an object is already in the set and only uses `equals` if there is a collision. The default hash code for objects is an internal id, so just because the two objects are equal doesn't mean they have the same hash code. In this case, there clearly wasn't a collision, so there was no need for the `HashSet` to call `equals`.

This is why you should always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`. See [this article](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) for more info on this topic. You should write a `hashCode` method that returns equal hash values for objects that are `equals`. For instance:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return number;
}
```

The general requirement for `hashCode` is that objects that satisfy `equals()` should return the same hash code. Note that there's no requirement that objects that fail an `equals()` test have different hash codes. If you return a constant (like Jayamohan suggests), that satisfies the `hashCode` contract; however, this will completely eliminate the benefits of using a `HashSet` and you might as well go with a simple `ArrayList`.

Comment: So it doesn't use the equals method but instead uses some kind of hash code?

Comment: @Sammy - Exactly. It only uses `equals` if two objects hash to the same bucket. This is part of what makes hash tables (and hash sets) so efficient--they don't have to test equality against most (and often any) elements of the set.

Answer (score 1):

While comparing the objects,

- `equals` method will **not** be called if *hashCode* differs
- `hashCode` method will **not** be called if (obj1 == obj2)

So in your case since you haven't overridden the hashCode method the hash code is different so equals is not being called. Try Overriding hashCode method as below, your equals method will be called.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}
```

[Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) API in Java states as below

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

So remember to override `hashCode` when you are overriding equals method.